# Создание таймера на php

Tags: php

Пытаюсь в голове сложить механизм создания таймера.
Задача:
Пользователь создает таймер сроком на 3 дня 15 часов.
После истечения времени должна запускаться функция, например отправка email.

Как это реализовать?
Я смог придумать как измерить время от начала запуска времени — сравнивать, записанную в БД отметку времени с временем сервера, но я не могу понять как запускать процессы по истечении этого времени?

Comment: Используйте cron-задания для выполнения php-скрипа по расписанию.

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но вам нужно посмотреть что такое устанавливаемые триггеры, возможно вам это поможет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью cron можно реализовать, поставить его на запуск через определенное время, и проверяешь есть ли в БД задания с временем запуска которое меньше текущего времени.